# Elasticsearch java API bulk delete not working

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm attempting perform a bulk delete of documents whose id's are derived from a previous search.  The query to determine the documents that are candidates for deletion is producing desired results (thousands of records) however the bulk delete only deletes 10 records at a time, even though I'm feeding it all of the results of the original query;

```
Client client = node.client();
BulkRequestBuilder bulkRequest = client.prepareBulk();

SearchResponse deletes = client.prepareSearch("my_index")
        .setTypes("my_doc_type")
        .setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_THEN_FETCH)
        .setQuery(boolQuery().mustNot(termQuery("tId", transactionId)))
        .execute()
        .actionGet();

long deleteHits = deletes.getHits().getTotalHits();

if (deleteHits > 0) {

    logger.info("Preparing to delete (" + deleteHits + ") " +
            "documents from index");

    Arrays.asList(deletes.getHits().getHits()).stream().forEach(h ->
            bulkRequest.add(client.prepareDelete()
                .setIndex("my_index")
                .setType("my_doc_type")
                .setId(h.getId())));
    }

    BulkResponse bulkResponse = bulkRequest.execute().actionGet();

    if (bulkResponse.hasFailures()) {
        throw new RuntimeException(bulkResponse.buildFailureMessage());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, the search response returns only top 10 results. So, while `deletes .getHits().getTotalHits()` can be in thousands or even in millions, the size of `deletes.getHits().getHits()` will never be more than you specified in the `size` parameter of your request, which 10 by default.

A naive approach would be to try paginating throw the results using normal search by changing the `from` parameter. However, this can lead to missing to delete some records since each command will execute a new search and the result of the next search can get shifted comparing to the previous search as a result of deleting records on the previous search.

A proper approach is to use specialized [scan and scroll search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scan-scroll.html) to paginate throw the records. This type of search will keep the results consistent between calls. An example, of this approach can be found in the [delete by query](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/master/plugins/delete-by-query/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/action/deletebyquery/TransportDeleteByQueryAction.java#L104) plugin that will be available in v2.0.

I also need to note that while the [delete by query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/docs-delete-by-query.html) functionality exists in the previous versions of elasticsearch and it might seem to be the easiest solution for your problem, I would still recommend to use scan/scroll because of [poor performance and fragility](https://www.elastic.co/blog/core-delete-by-query-is-a-plugin) of existing delete by query API implementation in pre-v2.0.

Answer (score 0):

`deletes.getHits().getTotalHits` give you the total number of hits for the search but  `SearchResponse deletes` do not contains all the results.
You'll need to paginate over it.

you'll need to use something like this to define the paging

`client.prepareSearch("my_index").setFrom(int from).setSize(int pageSize);`